# Notification setting up for an upcoming work item

Tags: notifications

I have a created a work item. The work item is to be done in next quarter. Can we setup an alert/notification, to be received 15 days prior to the date or so?

For a work item - I have proposed the start date to 01-February-2024. The assignee should get an reminder on 16-Jan-2024.

Comment: a work item in what? You have no mentioned any system, product etc. Please tag the proper thing you're talking about.